# Set CssClass on a label inside a Repeater, in a Template Col in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, nested, controls, repeater

I have a Repeater inside a Grid View control (Telerik).

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn column" HeaderText="<%$ resources: PARTNER_LIST_GRID_CATEGORY %>" UniqueName="TemplateColumn">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="myGridHeader" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="dlPartnerCat" OnItemDataBound="dlPartnerCat_OnItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPartCat" CssClass="k-margin-l-10-desktop" Text='<%#Eval("BusinessPartnerCategoryName")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <%--  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPartCat" CssClass="k-margin-l-10-desktop" Text='<%#Eval("BusinessPartnerCategoryName")%>' />
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>--%>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

I bind the data to it in a following way:

```
void BindPartners()
{
    var _partners = new BusinessPartnerRepo().GetAll(CompanyHelper.GetCompId()).Where(i => i.IsActive == true);
    var _p = new TD.Data.Entity.BusinessPartner();

    gvPartnerList.DataSource = _partners;
    gvPartnerList.Rebind();

    foreach (GridDataItem _dataItem in gvPartnerList.Items)
    {
        var _selectedItem = _dataItem.ItemIndex;
        var _list = _dataItem.MuchBetterFindControl<Repeater>("dlPartnerCat");
        var _id = (int)_dataItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[_selectedItem]["BusinessPartnerId"];

        if (_id > 0)
        {
            _p = _partners.FirstOrDefault(i => i.BusinessPartnerId == _id);

            if (_list != null)
            {
                _list.DataSource = _p.BusinessPartnerCategories.OrderBy(n => n.BusinessPartnerCategoryName);
                _list.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all of this works great. But I want to apply Css class to the label inside the repeater. This worked great with a single value (like I do with Status) and it even forks for the first value in the repeater..

```
protected void dlPartnerCat_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem _item in gvPartnerList.Items)
    {
        var _list = _item.MuchBetterFindControl<Repeater>("dlPartnerCat");

        foreach (RepeaterItem _ite in _list.Items)
        {
            var _partCatlbl = _ite.MuchBetterFindControl<Label>("lblPartCat");

            if (_partCatlbl != null)
            {
                switch (_partCatlbl.Text)
                {
                    case "Customer":
                        _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.CustomerClass;
                        break;
                    case "Customer - Supplier":
                        _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.Customer_SupplierClass;
                        break;
                    case "Supplier":
                        _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.SupplierClass;
                        break;
                    case "Agent":
                        _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.AgentClass;
                        break;
                    default:
                        _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.WarningClass;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

the value in the repeater can be multiple and I want to set different class based on the value (text) for the label in the repeater

[image: How it is now]

any ideas anybody??

Ok, I have resolved this ...at least partially

I altered the OnDataBound method for the repeater:

```
protected void dlPartnerCat_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridDataItem _item in gvPartnerList.Items)
        {
            var _list = _item.MuchBetterFindControl<Repeater>("dlPartnerCat");

            foreach (RepeaterItem _ite in _list.Items)
            {
                var _partCatlbl = _ite.MuchBetterFindControl<Label>("lblPartCat");

                if (_partCatlbl != null)
                {
                    switch (_partCatlbl.Text)
                    {
                        case "Customer":
                            _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.CustomerClass;
                            break;
                        case "Customer - Supplier":
                            _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.Customer_SupplierClass;
                            break;
                        case "Supplier":
                            _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.SupplierClass;
                            break;
                        case "Agent":
                            _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.AgentClass;
                            break;
                        default:
                            _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.WarningClass;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and the result are following:

[image]

as you can see all elements have css class applied exept the last one... anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove both `foreach` loops. There is no need to and it only add extra overhead.

```
protected void dlPartnerCat_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var _partCatlbl = e.Item.FindControl("lblPartCat") as Label

    if (_partCatlbl != null)
    {
        switch (_partCatlbl.Text)
        {
            case "Customer":
                _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.CustomerClass;
                break;
            case "Customer - Supplier":
                _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.Customer_SupplierClass;
                break;
            case "Supplier":
                _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.SupplierClass;
                break;
            case "Agent":
                _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.AgentClass;
                break;
            default:
                _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.WarningClass;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```