# Css Class not applied to last element in a repeater

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, webforms

I have a Repeater to display categories (see img). This works for all elements except the last one.

[image]

I use `OnDataBound` method to apply classes to elements based on text value:

```
 protected void dlPartnerCat_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridDataItem _item in gvPartnerList.Items)
        {
            var _list = _item.MuchBetterFindControl<Repeater>("dlPartnerCat");

            foreach (RepeaterItem _ite in _list.Items)
            {
                var _partCatlbl = _ite.MuchBetterFindControl<Label>("lblPartCat");

                if (_partCatlbl != null)
                {
                    switch (_partCatlbl.Text)
                    {
                        case "Customer":
                            _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.CustomerClass;
                            break;
                        case "Customer - Supplier":
                            _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.Customer_SupplierClass;
                            break;
                        case "Supplier":
                            _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.SupplierClass;
                            break;
                        case "Agent":
                            _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.AgentClass;
                            break;
                        default:
                            _partCatlbl.CssClass = ApplicationCssHelper.WarningClass;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

it does not matter which Category is last

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set CssClass on a label inside a Repeater, in a Template Col in a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842993/set-cssclass-on-a-label-inside-a-repeater-in-a-template-col-in-a-gridview)

Comment: It is, sorry about that. See duplicate for a solved answer :)